# 'CharacterSetSettings' in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I'm using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to create replication tasks. I noticed that in the TaskSettings JSON there's an attribute called `CharacterSetSettings`. However, there seems to be no documentation for this attribute.

I tried searching documentation and google for this attribute nothing comes up.

Task Settings JSON:

```
{
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "FullLobMode": false,
        "LobChunkSize": 0,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
        "LobMaxSize": 256,
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "TRUNCATE_BEFORE_LOAD",
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 1000,
        "CommitRate": 10000
    },
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            },
            {
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER",
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
            }
        ],
        "CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-altitude-staging-to-prod-instance",
        "CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task-RU2FBO6SGUASAODLXHJ63OYDAM"
    },
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "ControlSchema": "control",
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": true,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": true,
        "StatusTableEnabled": true
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
    },
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "StatementCacheSize": 50
    },
    "ValidationSettings": {
        "EnableValidation": true,
        "ValidationMode": "ROW_LEVEL",
        "ThreadCount": 5,
        "PartitionSize": 10000,
        "FailureMaxCount": 10000,
        "RecordFailureDelayInMinutes": 5,
        "RecordSuspendDelayInMinutes": 30,
        "MaxKeyColumnSize": 8096,
        "TableFailureMaxCount": 1000,
        "ValidationOnly": false,
        "HandleCollationDiff": false,
        "RecordFailureDelayLimitInMinutes": 0
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null
}
```

There should be documentation on `CharacterSetSettings`. I'd expect that documentation to be listed on [Specifying Task Settings for AWS Database Migration Service Tasks - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [Character Substitution Task Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.CharacterSubstitution.html). It seems to be fairly new.

> You can specify that your replication task perform character
>   substitutions on the target database for all source database columns
>   with the AWS DMS `STRING` or `WSTRING` data type. You can configure
>   character substitution for any task with endpoints from the following
>   source and target databases:
>
> Source databases:
>
> - Oracle
> - Microsoft SQL Server
> - MySQL
> - PostgreSQL
> - SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE)
> - IBM Db2 LUW
>
> Target databases:
>
> - Oracle
> - Microsoft SQL Server
> - MySQL
> - PostgreSQL
> - SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE)
> - Amazon Redshift
>
> The replication task completes all of the specified character substitutions before starting any global or table-level transformations that you specify through table mapping.

The object looks like this:

```
"CharacterSetSettings": {
    "CharacterReplacements": [ {
        "SourceCharacterCodePoint": int,
        "TargetCharacterCodePoint": int
        },
        [...]
    ],
    "CharacterSetSupport": {
        "CharacterSet": str,
        "ReplaceWithCharacterCodePoint": int
    }
}
```

DMS processes character substitution in two phases:

- In the first phase, `CharacterReplacements` is a list of objects that describe single replacements of one Unicode code point with another. For instance, if you wanted to replace `b` with `a`, set `SourceCharacterCodePoint` to `62`, `TargetCharacterCodePoint` to `61`.
- In the second phase, setting `CharacterSetSupport` makes DMS validate that all characters are valid for `CharacterSet` (i.e. `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, `ISO-8859-1`. Find the full list in the documentation) encoding. If it finds invalid characters, they will be replaced by `ReplaceWithCharacterCodePoint`.

For both phases, the special code point `0` can be used for deleting characters instead.